# I want to use wpadmin in django but having an issue

Tags: python, django, wp-admin

Hello everyone I want to integrate wpadmin by [barszczmm](https://github.com/barszczmm) into my django project but in his documentation he has written

Add `django.core.context_processors.request` to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting.
Icannot exactly understand what this means . I tried by adding this line `django.core.context_processors.request` in `setting.py` under `templates` -> `'context_processors'` but nothing happened and server gives the exception `InvalidTemplateLibrary at /admin/` .please tell me exactly what to do

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a compatibility issue (if you are using Django 2.X).
You probably encoutered that warning message while running your server:

`UserWarning: Django WP Admin 1.7.4 is not compatible with Django 2.1.1 and may not work properly. You should install Django WP Admin from 2.1.x branch.`

By the way, it seems that the repo is not maintained anymore (last update 3 years ago). So I think that there is no way to solve your problem (but installing Django 1.7 maybe...).